# Fetch, Decode and Re-encode JSON

Tags: php, json, instagram

I am attempting to fetch JSON from Instagram according to a number of URL parameters, the JSON is then decoded and then the objects required are then encoded into my own JSON format. Whilst I know this sound a little ridiculous, it is what is required. My only issue here is that for some reason it does not encode each section of JSON, it will only work for one item. The code is as below.

```
<?php

function instagram($count=16){

$igtoken = $_GET['igtoken'];
$hashtag = $_GET['hashtag'];


    $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$hashtag.'/media/recent/?access_token='.$igtoken.'&count='.$count;

        $jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));

$jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents($url)));
    foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {

            $response = array();
            $response["data"] = array();
            $data = array();
            $data["createdtime"] = $value->caption->created_time;
            $data["username"] = $value->caption->from->username;
            $data["profileimage"] = $value->caption->from->profile_picture;
            $data["caption"] = $value->caption->text;
            $data["postimage"] = $value->images->standard_resolution->url;

            array_push($response["data"], $data);
            $result = json_encode($response); 

    }

    return $result;
}

echo instagram();
?>
```

It will work for each section of JSON if I do something like this instead:

```
    $result .= '<li> 
                      '.$value->caption->from->username.'<br/>
                      '.$value->caption->from->profile_picture.'<br/>
                      '.$value->caption->text.'<br/>
                      '.$value->images->standard_resolution->url.'<br/>
                      '.$value->caption->created_time.'<br/>
                      </li>';
```

I feel I have bodged up somewhere with the array, however i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: your adding some html around your json encoded string? i am confused what your trying to do

Comment: Forget the HTML stuff, I was just doing that as a way of seeing the data I had parsed from Instagram prior to re-encoding it. I'm just saying it would output all 16 requested posts from Instagram in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if we move $response["data"] and $result varia out of foreach?

Have you tried this?

```
$response = array();
$response["data"] = array();
foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) {            

        $data = array();
        $data["createdtime"] = $value->caption->created_time;
        $data["username"] = $value->caption->from->username;
        $data["profileimage"] = $value->caption->from->profile_picture;
        $data["caption"] = $value->caption->text;
        $data["postimage"] = $value->images->standard_resolution->url;

        array_push($response["data"], $data);
}
$result = json_encode($response); 
return $result;
```